# Transforming Equations: Unable to change the equation from one form to other

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

There is this one differentiation problem in my textbook. I solved it by using Quotient rule and the author solved it by rationalising the denominator first. Now, I have two equations (I plotted them on a graphing calculator and both have the same graph so they are essentially the same thing written in different forms). For other questions, I am able to manipulate one equation and change it to another form; however, I am unable to do this here. Could someone help?

$$\dfrac14\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)=\dfrac14\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}{-x^2+1+x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)$$

Comment: Please enter using MathJax. I do not see any attachment.

Comment: Sorry. Image added.

Comment: Instead of pasting an image, please take the time to enter those expressions as text using MathJax. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers. You can find a quick reference for MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference),

Comment: @amd will surely do it next time onwards.

Comment: I have written the expressions under text form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some easily understood transformations, we have to prove that :

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}{-(\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)})^2+x\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}},$$

Simplifying the denominators by the common factor $\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}$, we are reduced to prove that :

$$\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}{-\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}+x},\tag{1}$$

which is a relationship of the form $A=\frac{B}{C}$.

Let us prove that $AC=B$ :

$$(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1})(-\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}+x)=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}$$

Expanding the LHS, we get :

$$-(x+1)\sqrt{x-1}+x\sqrt{x+1}-(x-1)\sqrt{x+1}+x\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}$$

a relationship which becomes evident by grouping terms containing $\sqrt{x+1}$ and $\sqrt{x-1}$ resp. in the LHS.

**Remark** : (1) could have been proved as well by using relationship :

$$x-\sqrt{x^2-1}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2}}\right)^2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I didn't think of that denominator common factor thing.